# final String data = await key.bundle.loadString(key.name);

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, mobile-development, lib

[[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewlf4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9D8O.jpg)
When I click on the application it gives me an error. i don't understand why If I have photos to add, I can. because I don't know what caused the error.
    `Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () { Get.to(LoginView()); });`